# How can I stop Angular $http from deserializing the response body?

Tags: angularjs, http, content-type

This:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/some/url/returning/json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

shows that Angular is giving me a JavaScript object as the first argument to my `success` handler. Presumably, it is trying to be smart by sniffing the content-type of the response.

This is undesired behavior. How do I tell Angular to give me the response body as a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The undesired behavior is caused by Angular's `transformResponse`. To turn this off, do:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/some/url/returning/json', transformResponse: [] }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It mentions in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) that the `responseType` config option can be used, presumably as:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/some/url/returning/json', responseType: 'text'})...
```

Comment: Unfortunately not; this does nothing. (And the documentation is crap -- it doesn't say what it's meant to do.)

Comment: Don't worry -- I found the answer. It's the `transformResponse` that's doing the evil. Thanks though!