# How to set contentType in angularjs $http.get

Tags: angularjs, content-type

I have following code in angular for calling a Web API that returns an array of bytes. 
I would like to set the ContentType to 'application/pdf', which is very simple to do in a jQuery ajax call, but cannot find a way to do this in angularjs.

**Question**: How would I do this for code below in angularjs?

```
  return $http.get('/api/v1/alarms/exportsummarytopdf?start=2011-03-
     30T05:00:00.000Z&end=2015-04-14T05:00:00.000Z')
    .then(getSummaryPdfExportComplete)
           .catch(function (message) {
               exception.catcher('XHR failed for getSummaryPdfExport')(message);
           });

        function getSummaryPdfExportComplete(response) {
            logger.info('getSummaryPdfExport: complete');
            return response.data;
        }
```

**UPDATE 1**:

When I go to a similar URL duirectly, then Chrome clearly shows content-type as 'application/pdf'. May be I need to use something else when calling a web api that returns an array of bytes.

[image]

The error displayed in Chrome is as below.
[image]

The headers for this failed request, when I use responseType: 'arraybuffer' is as below.
[image]

Comment: Content-Type is a response header.  Why would you wish to set it on a request?

Comment: @PassKit that's not correct but you typically wouldn't set it on a GET request as there's no request body

Comment: Perhaps Sunil means "Accept" here...

Comment: You pass in a headers object with your request:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
but really your server should be the one setting the content-type, not the client.

Comment: Try adding `{responseType: 'blob'}` or `{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}` after the URL as the second argument to `$http.get`, depending on how you want to use the data. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsetype

Comment: You could also try adding a `transformResponse` function (see docs), and modify the responseHeaders.

Comment: @Phil technically true, but it is only valid with POST and PUT requests.  The poster is using GET which as you rightly point out has no body.

Comment: @Phil, When I added  {responseType: 'blob'}  it gave me a '400 Bad Request' in Google Chrome developer tool.

Comment: @Sunil that's odd. I didn't think that would effect the request at all. What's the response body for that 400? Also, show your updated code

Comment: @Phil, Its "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: index"

Comment: Can you post the headers for the actual URL, not a 'similar' URL?

Comment: @PassKit, I just added the screenshot showing headers which is a screenshot from Google Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Looks like you've got a server error. The problem is not the content type.
`Status code: 400 Bad Request`
Either the parameters you're sending are not what the api is expecting, or the api has a bug that's causing it to throw an exception.

Comment: Yup, parameter "index" is what's causing the issue, not the `responseType` config. Once again, **show your updated code**

Comment: For future reference, because it bears repeating in case you missed it: `Content types for a GET request should be set on the server, NOT the client`

Comment: @Phil, where are you reading "index"?

Comment: @HankScorpio  couple of comments up (from OP) ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518266/how-to-set-contenttype-in-angularjs-http-get?noredirect=1#comment49112026_30518266. Seeing as that isn't a request parameter, I'd say it's definitely an internal error on the API. I'd also say it's returning the wrong status code; should be a 500

Comment: @HankScorpio,@Phil, Let me double check my code on server-side

Comment: You guys were right. It was a server-side problem, so I corrected the URL to inlcude all query string parameters but it now says: "Could not find a formatter matching the media type 'application/pdf' that can write an instance of 'Byte[]'."

Answer (score 5):

Short answer to the basic question is if you want to set a header in your $http.get() call, send it as part of the "config" (the second, optional parameter.)

E.g.:

```
$http.get('/api/v1/alarms/exportsummarytopdf?start=2011-03-
  30T05:00:00.000Z&end=2015-04-14T05:00:00.000Z',
  {headers: { 'Accept': 'application/pdf' });
```

To your specific question, it looks like you want "Accept" and not "Content-Type".

See [HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more info.

Comment: Would that reject content-types that aren't `'application/pdf'`?

Comment: Something tells me the server is going to return binary data no matter what the `Accept` header says

Comment: All depends on how the server is configured... though the sample URL here is "exportsummarytopdf" so I'm guessing that's what's coming out regardless.

Comment: Not sure that this will work for case above as it appears they are receiving a byte stream with no content type header in the response which the browser is interpreting as Text/Plain and returning the raw output.  If this is the case and the response then Adding an accept header would cause the request to fail.

Comment: as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287715/how-can-i-stop-angular-http-from-deserializing-the-response-body?rq=1

Comment: @PassKit OP has updated their question. The response has the correct `Content-type` header

Comment: The response headers posted are from 'a similar url' - I suspect that the API response is still not returning a response header.

Comment: @DavidPisoni, I tried Content-Type as you suggested but its still giving bad request with 400 code.

Comment: And it will continue to do so until you fix the problem with your API.

Comment: I did notice that a similar web api when called in another application had the 'Type' value as 'document' and not 'xhr', when one looks under the Network tab in Chrome Dev tools, but do not know how I could make the type as document for this request.